# Deque: swap first and last element without using STL

Tags: c++, swap, deque

I have to implement deque using linked list without stl.

**Issue:**
I got stucked with function swap, and I can't figure out where is a problem.

**My code you can see below:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int mData;
    Node* pPrev, *pNext;
    Node()
    {
        pPrev = pNext = NULL;
    }
    Node(int value)
    {
        mData = value;
        pPrev = pNext = NULL;
    }
};

class Deque
{
private:
    Node *pFront, *pRear;
    int mSize;
public:
    Deque()
    {
        pFront = pRear = NULL;
        mSize = 0;
    }
    void pushFront(int data)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node(data);
        if (newNode == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Error";
        }
        else
        {
            if (pFront == NULL)
            {
                pRear = pFront = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                newNode->pNext = pFront;
                pFront->pPrev = newNode;
                pFront = newNode;
            }
            mSize++;
        }
    }
    void pushLast(int data)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node(data);
        if (newNode == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Error";
        }
        else
        {
            if (pRear == NULL)
            {
                pFront = pRear = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                newNode->pPrev = pRear;
                pRear->pNext = newNode;
                pRear = newNode;
            }
            mSize++;
        }
    }
    void deleteFront()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            cout << "Deque is empty";
        }
        else
        {
            Node* temp = pFront;
            pFront = pFront->pNext;

            if (pFront == NULL)
            {
                pRear = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                pFront->pPrev = NULL;
            }
            delete temp;
            mSize--;
        }
    
    }
    void deleteLast()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            cout << "Deque is empty";
        }
        else
        {
            Node* temp = pRear;
            pRear = pRear->pPrev;

            if (pRear == NULL)
            {
                pFront = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                pRear->pNext = NULL;
            }
            delete temp;
            mSize--;
        }
    }


    void swap() 
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            cout << "Deque is empty";
        }
        else
        {
            Node* tmp_head = pFront;
            tmp_head->mData = pFront->mData;
            tmp_head->pNext = pFront->pNext;
            tmp_head->pPrev = pFront->pPrev;

            Node* tmp_rear = pRear;
            tmp_rear->mData = pRear->mData;
            tmp_rear->pNext = pRear->pNext;
            tmp_rear->pPrev = pRear->pPrev;

            while (tmp_head->pNext != NULL && pRear->pPrev!=NULL) {
                tmp_head = tmp_head->pNext;
                tmp_rear = tmp_rear->pPrev;
            }
            pRear = tmp_head;
            pRear->mData = tmp_head->mData;

            pFront = tmp_rear;
            pFront->mData = tmp_rear->mData;

        }

    }
    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return (mSize == 0);
    }
    int getSize()
    {
        return mSize;
    }
    void show()
    {
        Node* node = pFront;
        while (node != NULL) 
        {
            cout << node->mData << " ";
            node = node->pNext;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Deque deque;
    deque.pushFront(1);
    deque.pushFront(2);
    deque.pushFront(3);
    deque.show();
    deque.swap();
    deque.show();
}
```

Being quite new in c++ algorithms, thus don't judge me in case I did some mistakes:)If there is any questions regarding code, don't hesitate to ask.
Thank You in advance!

Comment: Very strong and simple recomendation. Very easy to implement. Do NOT try to swap the nodes. Just swap the value. So just swap the mData of the first and the last node . . .

Comment: That's not a deque, that's just a doubly linked list.

Comment: Note: `pRear` and `tmp_rear` point to the same object. Same for `tmp_head` and `pFront`. You just assign al those values to themselves in the first 8 statements of the `else` in `swap`...

Comment: @AM It's not always possible to swap value. One of the strengths of linked lists (b/c this is linked list, not deque) is that we don't assume that elements are movable. Example where it's useful is when you take the address of element and expect it to be const.

Comment: Note: The STL couldn't really help you here without throwing out pretty much everything you wrote. Plus it's not as easy to get an STL implementation as it was 25 years ago.

Comment: @AM `while (pFront->pNext != NULL && pRear->pPrev!=NULL) {
                pFront = pFront->pNext;
                pRear = pRear->pPrev;
            }
            int val = pFront->mData;
            pFront->mData = pRear->mData;
            pRear->mData = val;`  but still not working

Comment: You have all the machinery spread out over the other functions. You might want to extract that code into reusable helpers like `insert` and `extract`. Then to swap first and last, take them out of the list (without deleting them), and insert them again in opposite positions.